# Why is water in the asymmetric cylinder not capable of Simple Harmonic Motion?

Tags: kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I'm learning physics in a high school. I'm curious why water in the asymmetric cylinder is not capable of SHM.

[image]

I've learned that water in a symmetric cylinder can make a Simple Harmonic Motion. But my teacher says in a asymmetric cylinder can't make it. I'm curious why.

Thanks.

Comment: The one on the right is trying to execute two different motions, and can accomplish neither since the other side won't cooperate. A U-tube of area A or a alone is fine, but they will slosh back and forth at different frequencies.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for explanation. Can you explain this situation with some equations?

Comment: [Oscillation (SHM) of a Liquid in U Tube of Non Uniform Area](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewreX0xCJ7g)